# "General" normal equations?

Tags: linear-model, matrix

I am quite familiar with the usual OLS estimate for $\boldsymbol\beta$, given by
$$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}\mathbf{Y}$$
for the linear model $\mathbf{Y} = X\boldsymbol\beta + \boldsymbol\epsilon$.

My professor presented that instead of assuming $\text{Var}[\mathbf{Y}] = \sigma^2I$ ($I$ being the identity matrix), if $\text{Var}[\mathbf{Y}] = \Sigma$, then $$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = (X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X^{T}\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{Y}\text{.}$$

This was presented without proof. How is this derived? I don't see where in particular the original derivation is dependent on $\text{Var}[\mathbf{Y}] = \sigma^2I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can always (attempt to) solve the optimization problem 
$$\hat \beta = \textrm{argmin}_{\beta \in \mathbb R^p} ||Y - X\beta||^2$$

but this solution doesn't necessarily have the properties that we want if it is not the case that $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ where $E(\varepsilon_i) = 0$, $Var(\varepsilon_i) = \sigma^2$, and $Cov(\varepsilon_i, \varepsilon_j) = 0$ for $i \neq j$. For instance, if $Var(\varepsilon) \neq \sigma^2 I_n$ then we don't have the [Gauss-Markov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem).

If we instead do

$$
\hat \beta = \textrm{argmin}_{\beta \in \mathbb R^p} (Y - X\beta)^T \Sigma^{-1} (Y - X\beta)
$$ 
 (which is minimizing the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)) then we continue to enjoy properties that we want. This is called [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) and results in the estimator that you saw.

As the wikipedia article mentions, you can also view this as OLS on a transformation of your data where you multiply through by $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ (assuming $\Sigma$ is positive definite).